# Crystal Reports Suppress Group If Field Does Not Change

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

I want to suppress a group if a field does not change within that group. Here is a screenshot of my example data (the two red-boxed fields showing the groups that have the unchanging field):

[image: sample data]

As you can see the two groups, `reservation_number` 10002 and 10014, should be suppressed as their `amount` field does not change.

Ideally the above screenshot should become this:

[image]

Please note that there can be more than two `amount` rows in a group.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below process

Create a formula `@Initialize` and write below code and place in group header

Shared numbervar counter;
counter:=0

Create one more formula `count` and write below code and place in detail where you have data rows

```
    Shared numbervar counter;
    if PreviousIsNull(amount)
            then counter:=counter+0
            else if previous(amount) = amount
            then counter:=counter+0
            else if next(amount) = amount
            then counter:=counter+0
else counter:=counter+1
```

Create one more formula `result` and place in groupfooter

```
Shared numbervar counter;
Shared Numbervar counter1:=0;
counter1:=counter;
counter
```

Go to section expert and supress and write below condition:

```
EvaluateAfter({result})    ;
Shared numbervar counter;
    if counter = 0
    then
    true
     else false
```

Use below formula for supress of header:

```
EvaluateAfter({result});
Shared Numbervar counter1;
if counter1 = 0
        then
        true
         else false
```

Let me know if this works else will suggest other way

Comment: What section do I put this on? I tried both `Details` and `Group Header #1` and neither worked.

Comment: This is removing lines that have only two of the same amounts in a row but then other amounts after, such as `10007`, which it shouldn't.

Comment: @WolfieeifloW just edited the solution, try and let me know

Comment: Where do I put the last bit of code? If I put it only in `Group Header` the `Details` still show (and vice versa) and if I put it in both it's the same issue as before with `10007` not showing.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work still - and again where do I put the last chunk of code?

Comment: first code is in group header and detail and second code is in supress section

Comment: I have `Initialize` on the Group Header section, `count` on the Details section, and the last chunk of code in both sections Suppress via Section Expert. It's still suppressing `10007`.

Comment: made small change in second chunk of code, can you check

Comment: Still suppressing `10007`. Just to be sure and re-iterate I have `@Initialize` on the Group Header section, `@count` on the Details section, and the last chunk of code in BOTH sections Suppress via Section Expert.

Comment: your placement is correct but somehow logic is not reflecting correctly

Comment: Now all `reservation_number`s are gone. What I noticed with the previous code (and even this one) is that `10007` Detail lines were there but not the Group Header.  As you can see here the red-boxed lines are `10007` https://i.imgur.com/Gn6JoUY.png

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: That - and first `reservation_number` is missing and some `reservation_number`s that shouldn't show are (`10014` for example).